# AWS Rate Limiting API Gateway Endpoints By IP Address. (e.g. 100 Calls To An Endpoint Per Week For Each IP Address)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway, lambda-authorizer

I am developing an application that needs to rate limit / grant and deny users access to certain API gateway endpoints by IP address.

I want to have two limits placed on users:

1. One that is applied on an individual level (each user's ip address) restricting their access to certain endpoints.
   e.g. each ip address can only access:

- /endpoint1 (100 calls/week)
- /endpoint2 (50 calls/week)

2. Another that is a global quota applied to all users.
   e.g. the sum of all the requests for all ip address's for an endpoint can not exceed:

- /endpoint1 (10000 calls/week)
- /endpoint2 (5000 calls/week)

Originally, I planned on doing this by creating a lambda authorizer that would store users IP's and what endpoint they are attempting to access in a DynamoDB table and limit based off of that.

But I am wondering if there are pre-existing AWS solutions that do this.
One idea I had would be creating two usage plans for each endpoint. One with the global limit and another with the individual limit. I could then generate an API key for each new IP address that attempts to access the endpoint and store this in a DynamoDB table and return it using a lambda authorizer on each call by the same IP address. But I would also need to another api key for the global limit that is returned for all users which does not work because AWS does not allow for two api keys in the x-api-key header. Additionally, it seems that API keys are meant to be created manually rather than programmatically and also that there are limits on the number that can be created.

In summary, is my original idea (limiting with just DynamoDB and the lambda authorizer with no AWS API keys) a valid approach? I would essentially be reimplementing the same system AWS already offers with their API keys which is not ideal, so I am also wondering if there are any already existing solutions or AWS tools I could leverage to accomplish the rate limiting I am looking for.

Comment: You should definitely explore [WAF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-rate-based.html). It has limitations with respect to your use case, but still worth exploring.